# Drop down selection not registered when form submitted quickly?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have noticed a strange thing that happens on my web app when the server is under heavy loads (I am remoting on to the Windows Server).

I have a drop down box which is generated dynamically (server side). When I make a selection and quickly press the submit button to indicate my selection the next page does not register my selection but if I do it a bit more slowly it will.

I have not come across this before, has anyone? I know its a small issue but there are a lot of "trigger happy" users, including me...

should I put a delay before the form is submitted? If I do, I can only guess the right amount of time.

Or is there an underlying problem with my web app?

Thanks all

Here is the HTML page in question: http://pastebin.com/cQjXbeeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing anything with the value of that drop down list? It sounds like you are encountering the following scenario...

1. User selects from the list
2. The onchange event puts the value into a hidden field
3. The form submits and the value from the hidden field is stored somewhere

This would explain why you can submit the form before the value has "registered" - as the submit happens before the onchange has done its thing.

If this is the case (and by all means it may not be) then you need to check the value of the select list in the onsubmit action of the form, to ensure it is correct before the submit occurs.

If you don't think this is the case, please post a simple example so people can write a more informed answer.

Comment: That's the suprising thing! There is no javascript on the page that does anything with the form. Only a JQuery plugin to fix the transparent png issue on IE - but thats it. How else could this happen? What generates the post query string and when does this happen? I am guessing its the browser and it does it when the submit is pressed.